# Let sidebar take space of content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to best implement a sidebar, like the one in the new google plus

I'm using MaterializeCSS

where the "main" content of the page it's width decreases when the sidebar is open and it becomes the fullpage width when the sidebar is closed.

I'm trying to do this with the ui-router.

This is my current setup:

```
<header>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
</header>

<main ui-view="container"></main>

<footer>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</footer>
```

and each element has it's corresponding controller. 
I was thinking of creating a new controller for the sidebar.

But I can't seem to make this work like I want:
this is what I tried:

```
<main>
    <div class="navigation" ng-hide="shownav"><span class="flow-text">This div is 7-columns wide on pushed to the right by 5-columns.</span></div>
    <div class="content" ui-view="container"></div>
</main>
```

css:

```
main {
    width: 100%
}
.navigation {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
.content {
    min-width: 80%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: If you are using the MaterializeCSS they have a sideNav ready to go : http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html

Answer (score 0):

Work with `float:right` and `float:left`, then position the footer using `position: absolute` with the parameters like `bottom:0` and `left:0`to position on the bottom and left of the page, setting a width that I want.
Then mark the divs with `background-colors` and text to see exactly whats happening when I'm coding.

All your content wrapped inside the `<main>`, because it's where it's gonna the left bar and the content.

I'm sorry if I couldn't explain better

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.navigation {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}
.content {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
</header>

<main ui-view="container">


  <main>
    <div class="navigation" ng-hide="shownav"><span class="flow-text">This div is 7-columns wide on pushed to the right by 5-columns.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content" ui-view="container">aaaaaa</div>
  </main>


</main>

<footer>
  <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: And this doesn't take in account when the sidebar is closed that the content has to become fullscreen width as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/8vx1m4uw/1/